# Memory ReAllocation

Tags: winapi, memory, allocation

What is the right and best way to reallocate memory?
for example I allocate 100 bytes with WinAPI function HeapAlloc
then I fill 100 bytes of that memory with some data and now I want to add more new data at end of previous...

What Should I do?
Make a new allocation with more bytes and then copy old+new to new location and free old memory?
Or there is some way to allocate new memory at end of old data and then copy only new data?

Comment: anyway realloc-ating is not a free-of-overhead action, so you should limit the numbers of required realloc... if you know you have to add N bytes after 100 bytes, alloc N+100 at the beginning and avoid realloc; if you know that you can need a N amount of extra memory per "data", alloc 100+N*m where m is chosen according to your need to limit the probable number of realloc and memory extra usage in the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use [HeapReAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366704%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) since Windows will no doubt have optimisations in place if it can just expand the memory without copying data.

For example, I've seen implementations of `realloc` (the C standard one) which checks to see if the current block can just absorb a free block following it. If so, it does that to avoid a copy operation. If not, it allocates the new memory and does the copy before freeing the old.

Another advantage of that is that you minimise the extra memory required. In a copy version, you have to have two copies of the current data in existence at some point.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm going to try it :)

Answer (score 1):

[HeapReAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366704(VS.85).aspx)?